# How to use "thingamajig"

Tags: word-usage

I know when I have to use thingamajig, yes, when I don't know the precise word during the conversation.

What I want to know:

1. Is that word can be used in written language as well?
2. How to use that word? Any example sentences would be appreciated.

I am adding one more questin.

3. Can I use this word in questions?

Comment: Pretty much the same way you'd use "whatchamacallit".  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22thingamajig%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: This is the first time I have ever seen the word written down. I first learned to read in 1956.

Comment: Ooh, really?    Can't believe.

Comment: @HotLicks You mean a doodad?

Comment: @MikeGraham - No, I mean a "dingbob for a doodattle".

Comment: @NigelJ It's sometimes spelled _thingummyjig_.

Comment: A quick google search will show dictionary definitions with example sentences. It's a fairly common word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster, it's basically a placeholder word for something else.

> noun
> something that is hard to classify or whose name is unknown or forgotten

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thingamajig

This would allow it to be used nearly any place a noun would be usable. And, generally speaking, any word that's used verbally can be written down.

> That thingamajig broke while I was trying to fix the washing machine.
>
> Hey, can you hand me the thingamajig to your left?
>
> I got a new gadget last night. I saw the, uh, thingamajig on TV last week and it finally came in the mail. It slices, dices, and makes Julienne fries!
>
> What's the name of that thingamajig over there? That thing next to the copier.
>
> I need to order this thingamajig here, the whatchamacallit, um, the doohickey, ugh, this thingy. Oh, right it's a flour sifter.

Here's the definitions for the other words I used, which are similar and generally used interchangeably with thingamajig.

whatchamacallit:

> Whatchamacallit, a shortened version of "what you may call it",
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whatchamacallit

doohickey:

> A thing (used in a vague way to refer to something whose name one cannot recall)
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doohickey

thingy:

> something that is hard to classify or whose name is unknown or forgotten: THINGAMAJIG
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thingy

## Edit:

As DJClayworth mentions, there's a few other words that mean the same thing. There's online examples for "oojamaflip", although I can't remember hearing it ever used. And a handy thesaurus gives us several other words that are essentially nonsense words that have gained a foothold, simply for their lack of specific meaning.

> doodad, gizmo, thingamabob, widget, jigger

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/thingamajig

And another one I just remembered: whatsit. A similar word, whosit, is more generally used towards people rather than things, but saying "whosit-whatsit" can sometimes cover everything.

And I'm sure there's a wide variety of similar, locale/cultural specific words that I haven't listed in my not comprehensive list. It'd be interesting to have more suggestions in the comments, but I'm not sure if that's exactly relevant to the topic.

Comment: Also thingamibob, oojamaflip. And once upon a time "widget" meant that until the UI programmers took it over.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I've never heard of "oojamaflip" before. I had to look that up to see if it was a real word. It doesn't seem to appear in MW, but plenty of other places have it, so I'm going to have to remember that to confuse other people with.  :-)

Comment: My Dad used to say "thingamiflip and oojamabob", but I think that was just a Dad joke.

Comment: It's hard to pronounce. :(

Comment: @O.o, if you break it down, it's easier: thing-a-ma-jig. Once you get it, you can speed it up pretty pretty easily. Or were you talking about "oojamabob"? Yeah, that one's not exactly easy: oo-ja-ma-bob.

Comment: Is 'oojamaflip' a BrE word? I've never heard it (AmE), but it could be all over the place where I'm not listening.

Comment: I was talking about oojamabob. Btw, oojamabobs is correct?

Comment: @O.o, making any of these words plural is just following the standard convention. Adding an "s" works fine for most; and gizmos, thingies, and doohickeys all work in spellcheck. Trying thingamajiggers would be considered by some (including me) to be plural of thingamajig, although thingamajigger can be used singularly, too, but they don't work in spell check, yet Googling them shows results.

Comment: It should be noted that the words from the thesaurus entry for *thingamajig* that are quoted here are not its exact synonyms. *Gizmo* and *widget*, for example, seem to imply a certain degree of internal complexity. It would, however, be difficult to make it fully explicit what the differences among them are.

Comment: This answer focuses on the semantics of the word, but full competence in using it also requires awareness of its register. The word should definitely not be used in formal contexts. There is, moreover, a certain, for want of a better word, cuteness to it that makes it suitable for some settings but not others. This, however, can't be easily articulated in the form of some straightforward rules. It would thus be prudent for the learners of English not to try to use it themselves, until they have heard it used by others often enough to develop a sense of when it is appropriate.

Comment: @jsw29, it's true that these style of words generally shouldn't be used in a formal setting, but it's also considered that the people using this site aren't generally new to English. The site for English Language Learners would be ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: How can I evaluate my English level to make sure if I am new or not?

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Placeholder names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name). They can be and often are individually creative.

Comment: That link on Wikipedia doesn't give a great answer.

Comment: @computercarguy Thanks for example sentences. Now I see some more silly words which make me to continue the conversation even though I don't know precise word, like oojamaflip or doohickeys. Can I use these word like example sentences just by changing thingamajig to these words?

Comment: @O.o, yes, most of these words can be used interchangeably. There's a few words that have a technical or "complexity" implication, like widget and gizmo, but I don't think too many people would correct you about that in general conversation. Some would, but they are either trying to help you or are just nitpicking. Have fun using the new words!

Comment: @computercarguy thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @O.o, glad to be able to help!